# How to update the template of a widget in BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I've built a widget using the content/widget-templates api endpoint using this data as the body in the request

```
{
  "name": "Test Widget One",
  "template": "<h1>Test Widget One</h1>",
  "schema": [
       {
      "type": "tab",
      "label": "Content",
      "sections": []
       }
    ]
}
```

What do I do if I want to edit that template? If I repost this request with a new template it will create a new widget with the same name. I've taken the provided template uuid and formed a request like so

```
{
  "name": "Test Widget One",
  "widget_configuration": {
    "images": [
      {
        "image_url": "{{where-the-image-should-link-to}}",
        "image_source": "https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-n0i50vy/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/91/309/thekinfolktablecover_1024x1024__80715.1456436719.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on"
      },
      {
        "image_url": "{{where-the-image-should-link-to}}",
        "image_source": "https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-n0i50vy/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/109/361/kinfolkessentialissue_1024x1024__22507.1456436715.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on"
      },
      {
        "image_url": "{{where-the-image-should-link-to}}",
        "image_source": "https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-n0i50vy/images/stencil/500x659/products/85/282/livingwithplants_grande__26452.1456436666.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on"
      }
    ]
  },
   "widget_template": {
    "uuid": "my-uuid",
    "template": "<h1>This is an update to test widget One</h1>"
  },
  "widget_template_uuid": "my-uuid"
}
```

The response reports no errors, but no update is made to the actual template of the widget.

This is the response I get back: *(I replaced the uuid's with just 'uuid' for the example's sake)*

```
{
    "data": {
        "uuid": "uuid",
        "name": "Test Widget One",
        "widget_configuration": {
            "images": [
                {
                    "image_url": "{{where-the-image-should-link-to}}",
                    "image_source": "https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-n0i50vy/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/91/309/thekinfolktablecover_1024x1024__80715.1456436719.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "{{where-the-image-should-link-to}}",
                    "image_source": "https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-n0i50vy/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/109/361/kinfolkessentialissue_1024x1024__22507.1456436715.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "{{where-the-image-should-link-to}}",
                    "image_source": "https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-n0i50vy/images/stencil/500x659/products/85/282/livingwithplants_grande__26452.1456436666.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on"
                }
            ],
            "_": {
                "id": "id"
            }
        },
        "widget_template": {
            "uuid": "uuid",
            "name": "Test Widget One",
            "schema": [
                {
                    "type": "tab",
                    "label": "Content",
                    "sections": []
                }
            ],
            "template": "<h1>Test Widget One</h1>",
            "date_created": "2020-08-05T17:46:37.802Z",
            "date_modified": "2020-08-05T17:46:37.818Z",
            "kind": "custom",
            "storefront_api_query": "",
            "icon_name": "default",
            "template_engine": "handlebars_v3",
            "client_rerender": false,
            "site_id": 1000,
            "current_version_uuid": "uuid",
            "channel_id": 1
        },
        "date_created": "2020-08-05T18:04:24.512Z",
        "date_modified": "2020-08-05T18:04:24.512Z",
        "description": "",
        "storefront_api_query_params": {},
        "site_id": 1000,
        "version_uuid": "uuid",
        "channel_id": 1
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

What do I need to do to make an update to the template of a custom widget that has already been uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can Delete or Update an existing template using the correct API call and HTTP "method".

For example you can do a HTTP DELETE or a PUT (POST is what you seem to be doing which is adding a new template). Ensure you set the correct uuid in the path below to update or delete it:

```
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{{$$.env.store_hash}}/v3/content/widget-templates/:uuid
```